Animated movie from early '00s about a boy transported to a toy world after being given special imagination-related powers by mistake
I need help in finding this animated movie from my childhood...
Movie description: A girl/queen wants to gives magical "hero" powers to a boy she adores but she accidentally gives it to another boy. They are transported to a toy world where the boy must save them. The movie revolves around the power of imagination of the boy and at one point of the point, he looses imagination and becomes dull...
Year: Must be from 2002-2007 range and I saw it on Cartoon Network (India) channel
Format: Colour and the movie is animated
It is similar to The Lego Movie, though the hero in LEGO embraces his shitty imagination. In this movie, his imagination saves the day.

This is possibly The Toy Warrior (2005)
From IMDB:

The Land Of Toys is a world of pure imagination, ruled by the popular doll Princess Sherbet, but when the mysterious Dark One threatens Sherbet's toy kingdom, she turns to the real world in search of a heroic Warrior Prince... Unfortunately, she ends up with the imaginative trouble-maker Jinoo. When Jinoo accidentally touches Sherbet's magical Warrior Stone, the spunky sixth-grader is suddenly transported to the Land Of Toys to become the powerful Toy Warrior! Aided by the reluctant Princess Sherbet, the transforming Police-bot, R.J., and Jinoo's amazingly loyal backpack, Ping, Jinoo is ready to play Toy Warrior and chase the dark forces across the landscape of imagination. The evil is spreading and now both the real world and the very Well of Imagination itself are at stake! Our only hope is a hero with heart... the Toy Warrior Jinoo!

The time period fits and the princess picking a boy by mistake

Ding Ding! We have a winner! Thanks for the memories! :D
